What is the significance of the Latin inscription "IN NAVE EXEPEDITVS SIS TAM CELER QVAM VENTVS" on the divination table?
In Agatha All Along S01E07, "Death's Hand in Mine," a Latin inscription appears on a divination table that seems connected to the episode's themes of time and death. The episode features Lilia Calderu (played by Patti LuPone), a divination witch whose consciousness travels between her past and future selves.
At approximately 15:07 in the episode, in a scene set during Lilia's past, we can see the inscription "IN NAVE EXEPEDITVS SIS TAM CELER QVAM VENTVS" on one side of the table used by Lilia and her mentor. (Not to be confused with the tarot card table in another scene set in the Witches' Road, the present, with the English inscription "Your path winds out of time.")
Google Translate translates the Latin inscription as "You are as fast as the wind in a ship," and OpenL translates it as "Be as swift as the wind in the ship," though I'm not sure how accurate these translations are.


What significance does this Latin phrase hold for the episode's plot or Lilia's character?

This translator says: "Having departed in a ship, you are as swift as the wind of death.". I don't know anything about this kind of thing, but it almost sounds like a farewell to a departed one or something you could write on a tombstone?

@Clockwork "Mors" (death) seems to be part of another sentence/phrase, so I removed it (post now edited with the translation without "mors").

A Reddit discussion about the same thing. One person with rusty Latin translated it into: "aboard the ship, you are as fast as the wind".

If there is another sentence there involving the word death, perhaps these two sentences should be read together in order to get the full meaning.

That took me down a rabbit hole involving St. Expeditus that almost resulted in me ordering a figurine over Amazon...

@ArlettaS Yes, there appears to be another inscription near the first one, beginning with the word "mors" ("death"). However, the rest is cut off from view, and that's the only word visible.

I don't believe there was a significance to those particular words. However, it seems the other words had significance. This article on Deadline - an interview with the showrunner about that episode - includes a question about the table's words. And while it is the other phrase which is discussed, note his last sentence.

DEADLINE: Did the runes around the rim of the table. Did those have any certain meaning? There was of course the “Your path runs out of time” for Lilia’s trial.
SCHAEFFER: Your path winds out of time was meant to be of consequence, and there were so many iterations of what Lilia’s trial would be, and what the spread would be, and what the verbiage of all of it would be. “Your path winds out of time” was something that stuck through all of the iterations. Also because The Witches’ Road, your path, it felt correct for the theme and the world of the show. The specific runes, they’re not directly, of import on what’s transpiring In that moment.


I believe the English "Your path runs out of time" inscription is on a different divination table in another scene set in the Witches' Road (the present). The scene I'm referring to was set in Lilia's past.

The tarot card table with the English inscription of "Your path runs out of time"
